# Where does the tmpname function write temporary files in a Sun Solaris environment?

Tags: c, gcc, temp, solaris-10, sun

I am in a Unix environment (Sun Ultra 5 with gcc v.2.95.3) and I am trying to understand where my compiler writes temporary files using the tmpnam function. I am aware that this works is deprecated but mine was only curiosity.
I acted like this:
I ran this source in c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char nomefile[L_tmpnam];

    strcpy(nomefile, "my_file.txt");
    tmpnam(nomefile);

    getchar();

    return(0);
}
```

while waiting for the return key to be pressed, the program should create a temporary file (somewhere in the file system) named my_file.txt. So from another terminal I start the search in this way (as superuser):

find / -name my_file.txt -print

unfortunately it does not find it. Yet in the book I'm reading it says that this function (tmpnam) unlike the tmpfile function, you can specify the name of the temporary file and write it somewhere in the filesystem.

Comment: use `strace your_program` to see what it does. BTW: the tempfile might not be visible in the mounted file systems.

Comment: unfortunately it gives me a mistake: # strace a.out -> ERROR: unable to open /dev/log... I tried as superuser and gives me another error: ERROR: tracer already exists

Comment: *...the program should create a temporary file...*. Actually, `tmpnam` doesn't create a file. It creates a unique file name, using the string you give it as a base, and returns a pointer to that name which you can then use as a name for a temporary file. Looks like you didn't use it. Did you check `man tmpnam` on your system?

Comment: I saw the tmpnam manual as you recommended me @lurker. The directory is contained in the P_tmpdir macro (/var/tmp). You're right, the files are stored according to a unique name decided by the compiler, both if the argument is NULL, and if a name is used. In fact, a pointer is missing from my source.

Comment: @wildplasser: Solaris's `strace` command does something different than what you're expecting.  The Solaris command for tracing system calls, analogous to Linux's `strace`, is called `truss`.

Comment: @lurker: Actually I don't think it uses the string as a base for the name.  It generates the name from scratch and stores it in the given buffer, whose previous contents are ignored and overwritten.  You might be thinking of `tempnam`.

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right. Digital Unix had it too.

Comment: @NateEldredge right, thanks for catching that. I did get them mixed up.  Nonetheless, the main issue still stands.

Answer (score 0):

The correct source for identifying where temporary files are written is the following. As was suggested to me in the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char buffer[L_tmpnam] = "my_file.txt";
    char *ptr;

    tmpnam(buffer);
    printf("Temporary name 1: %s\n", buffer);

    ptr = tmpnam(NULL);
    printf("Temporary name 2: %s\n", ptr);

    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
Temporary name 1: /var/tmp/aaagXay5b
Temporary name 2: /var/tmp/baahXay5b
```